# Why are event types typically stored within an event's class definition?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, events, event-handling

In all the ActionScript examples I come across, people write custom events with the types defined inside the custom event's class definition. But, in my experience, it makes more sense for the object dispatching an event to own its own definition of that event (which, in ActionScript 3, is a String).

[EDIT: After writing this question, I've found there to be cases for both positions -- in some situations, event types should be stored on the event object, and, in others, they should be stored on the object dispatching the event.]

Please tell me what your take is on this and where you find yourself storing event types.

Comment: Is this truly a Java question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the last few years, I have actually been using a combination of these, mainly in the context of PureMVC.  Flash instances (view components) catch Flash events, and then dispatch an Event, where the type is a static string defined in that class.  The mediator catches the view components events, and then sends notifications where the notes are defined in the central application facade class.  I also try as much as possible to not subclass Event, and to minimize passing data around in note bodies.

I feel that this allows the most flexibility to rework both interfaces and application logic, and also provides more reuse of proxies and mediators/components between applications.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term, "note". Can you explain this?

Comment: Sorry about that.  Note is a PureMVC term.  The term may be unofficial, but it is used throughout much of the sample code.  Notification is the class name for messages.  The instance / parameter is typically called "note".  Every notification (ie, note) has a name and a body associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

If event the dispatcher has code pertaining to the definition of the event than the dispatcher arguably is in-cohesive. I would tend more towards having the event dispatcher implement a stable interface thus protecting it from variations in the events. This will also reduce coupling to the dispatcher and allow for greater flexibility in handling events.